# Chrome randomly render problems in Persian content

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, web

After update of google chrome I've faced with an Issue that sometimes the pages in our website not render in right way. some component got missed or rendered in bad way. I tried to hide or show them, change the margins after loading of page and things like them. but the problem is still here.
Our website is a local Persian website and it's [divar.ir](http://divar.ir)  and there are 2 pictures of two different type of render with same, exact same code.
[image: wrong render]
[image: Right Render]

Is there any way to avoid this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is that you make sure you have a have a good CSS reset script set that returns your web page to a known starting position and defaults. And then build it up from there...

Your site its mostly doing simple CSS stuff so mostly that should not be an issue. There is a JavaScript error so that may be effecting the adding of classes or attributes in script (if you do that).

As for protecting yourself from Browsers differences - there is not a lot you can do other than build content using the most basic / widely available standards available to you at the time, but you site aesthetics are directly linked to the features you can use, so a balance has to be struck.

And really protecting your site from the effects of a manufacturer new browser release is impossible. Even if you don't upgrade your browser, you can bet people who use your site will upgrade theirs.

Comment: I checked everything even resetting css stuff, we faced this error from build 43 of google chrome. and no error is happening in java-script. I saved  it in a file and the error is still happening. not everytime, randomly..